# Prevent onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) goes in an infinite loop

Tags: android, accessibility, accessibilityservice, accessibility-api

I've got an `AccessibilityEvent` which can stop app automatically. But when starting app info intent, it goes to infinite loop of turn on/off alert dialog.

How can I prevent it ? Here's the code:

```
 @Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    if (AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED == event
            .getEventType()) {
        AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = event.getSource();
        if (nodeInfo == null) {
            return;
        }

            List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> list = nodeInfo
                    .findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.android.settings:id/force_stop_button");
                for (AccessibilityNodeInfo node : list) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "check1 = " + check);
                    node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
                    check = true;
                }

                list = nodeInfo
                        .findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText("CANCEL");
                for (AccessibilityNodeInfo node : list) {
                    node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
                }
                }
            }
```

And by the way, any idea to get the `force_stop_button` clicked immediately after the app info intent started ?

EDIT: I think the problem is in `AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED`. If I bypass that check, it works, but really hard to control.

Comment: I am also doing the same thing and my app is also crashing. Can you suggest what you did to rectify this problem?

Comment: crashing ? Any log ?

Comment: It crashes after a while. In the log it comes as 'Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB'... 'Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB'... 'Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB' like this and then it crashes

Comment: sound like memory leak: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29193726/android-cache-background-process-is-increasing-continuously

Comment: btw, use findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText(string) is an option :))

Comment: i used findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText(string) same problem :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172752/discussion-between-aayushi-and-chris-maverick).

Answer (score 2):

In your code, whenever the AccessibilityService detects the Force Stop button in Settings activity, it is clicked. 
Now, a dialog will be shown with two buttons : Ok & Cancel. 
You are then performing click action on cancel button.

So, App Info -> Dialog -> Cancel -> App Info -> Dialog -> Cancel ...

is the loop you will get.

Change `list = nodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText("CANCEL");`

to `list = nodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText("OK");`

In order to click a node, you have to add some delay :

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
    }
}, 300);
```

Comment: Actually that's not what I want to ask.
Because it doesn't even click "Force Stop". So why should I care about clicking "Cancel" or "OK" ?

Comment: In my code now, actually there is a few "delayed" code. But it's very passive.

First, if my phone's just been doing a really heavy job and I run this code, 300ms seems not enough. Second, I think the code should be delayed is "findnode", not the "performAction" one.

But anyway, one upvote :D

Comment: Ya but i do think delay on performAction will works. Thanks anyway ;)